# how to call a custom function onSelect shadcn ui date picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, datepicker, react-hook-form

I'm still learning and working on a personal project using `react`, `typescript` and `Shadcn UI library`. According to my following code, in the Form I have a Shadcn UI date picker and I want to call a custom function using the selected date on onSelect function.
Also I need to get the selected date to a `useState`
how do I do that?

```
return (
    <Form {...form}>
      <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="space-y-4">
        <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-6">
          <div className="w-full">
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="date"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem >
                  <FormLabel>Appointment Date</FormLabel>
                  <Popover>
                    <PopoverTrigger asChild>
                      <FormControl>
                        <Button
                          variant={"outline"}
                          className={cn(
                            "w-full justify-start text-left font-normal",
                            !field.value && "text-muted-foreground"
                          )}
                        >
                          {field.value ? (
                            format(field.value, "EEEE, d MMM yyyy")
                            
                          ) : (
                            <span>Pick a date</span>
                          )}
                          <CalendarIcon className="ml-auto h-4 w-4 opacity-50" />
                        </Button>
                      </FormControl>
                    </PopoverTrigger>
                    <PopoverContent className="w-auto p-0" align="center">
                      <Calendar
                        mode="single"
                        selected={field.value}
                        onSelect={field.onChange}
                        disabled={(date) =>
                          date > new Date() || date < new Date("1900-01-01")
                        }
                        initialFocus
                      />
                    </PopoverContent>
                  </Popover>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
          </div>
        <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
      </form>
    </Form>
  );
```

Comment: Hello Tharisha, can we make it more clear? do you want to call a custom function if calendar value changed? do this custom function return any value that can be used in validation of new selected date? why do you want to store the value in a useState?

Comment: Hi Hedi M. Aziz,
I have a time selector dropdown also. I want to do an API call to fetch the available times according to the selected date. That's what I want to do. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: There is multiple methods based on your requirements, if you don't and won't have field validation (such as yup and zod), you can trigger the API call in calender's onSelect and putting the result in a state then give the time picker that state as the source of truth, but I don't recommend it. You can access the selected date via react-hook-form's _getValue_ and _watch_, and pass the value to a custom component that responsible for rendering the time picker AND calling the API for available times, it's a better implementation of separation of concerns.

Comment: I don't exactly know how every aspects of your application, so I couldn't choose the best way and make it an answer.